# Copy a row in a sheet with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google Apps Script so I am sorry if this is a very basic question. I haven't been able to find something that matches exactly what I need, so I will ask here.

I have a test spreadsheet with one sheet right now called Sheet1. I have data in the cells c3:F3. This data changes as it gets updated frequently.  I want to save these values in the same sheet appending it on a row below, starting from row c7:f7 on a set time daily.

It could look something like this
2022-12-15   1 2 4
2022-12-16   5 3 1

How would I go about doing something like this?

All I have so far is just this:

function CopyRow() {
let sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

let dataRange　=　sheet.getRange(2,3,1,3).getValues();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do that:

```js
function appendRow() {
  const sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Sheet1!C3:F3');
  appendRows_(sourceRange.getSheet(), sourceRange.getValues(), sourceRange.getColumn());
}
```

For that to work, you will need to paste the [`appendRows_()`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) and `getLastRow_()` utility functions in your script project.

You can schedule the function to run once a day using a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).